# How do I manage access control to a git repository on a file system?

Tags: git, version-control

If I put initialize a bare repository to a network drive and push and pull from it, is there a way  for me to allow others to clone the repo, but not push back to the master branch ?  I would like to review code before it goes back into the master branch.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of network share?  NFS?  SMB?

Comment: SMB on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either:

- put in  place an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [**gitolite**](http://gitolite.com/), which allows you to protect the master branch.
- or put a different repo for them to push to, which can be managed by **[gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)** (for code review purposes).
- or manage your bare repos with a full-fledged repo hosting service like **[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/)**

Comment: Hmmm.  I denied access to a specific user on the windows file system and they could still push to the remote master branch.  When I create the --bare repository is there a way to password protect it against a push ?

Comment: @BillGreer only by putting a listener in front of the repo (ssh or Apache)